# Can top show more than 100% in %MEM?

Tags: top

Can the %MEM value for a process show more than 100% in top output?Is this ever possible?

Answer (score 2):

No. The `%MEM` column represents physical memory usage, and normal processes cannot even *reach* 100%, since the kernel always occupies some part of it.

Comment: What if it is using some swap? Theoretically can it ever be more than 100%?

Comment: I did say *physical* memory. Swap doesn't count. (My test program only reached 85% after allocating 6 GB of memory on a 4 GB machine.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does because the value shown is the percentage of physical memory excluding swap and another think to take account of is the number of cores that the processor have and maybe when reaching more 100 % in one core we use the other cores